# How to get one row from table 2 (have blob column) for each row in table 1?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this query to get the first row from t2 that matches the primary key in t1 but I'm not getting the right results as I cant find the right way to write the query

```
select t1.id as id , t1.title as title ,t2.fId, t2.image as image ,t2.fName as fName ,t2.fType as fType
         from (select data_TBL.ID as id ,data_TBL.INT_STATUS as status,data_TBL.int_TYPE as type , data_TBL.TXT_TITLE as title ,data_TBL.dat_trans_date as cDate from data_TBL  
         ORDER BY  dat_trans_date DESC ) t1,
         (select int_data_id as fId ,int_category as category ,txt_attach_type as fType,txt_filename as fName,blob_file as image from data_attach_tbl
         where  int_category=1 and ROWNUM=1 and data_attach_tbl.int_data_id = id) t2
         where 
          t1.type = 11
         AND t1.status >= 1
         and ROWNUM <=6
```

query conditions :

1. the result should be ordered desc
2. for each row in t1 fetch one row from t2 (data_attach_tbl.int_data_id = id)
3. 6 rows are the final result

sample

```
t1     id     date            vac_title 
       1      15/10/2018      test 1
       2      20/10/2018      test 2
       3      21/10/2018      test 3
       4      22/10/2018      test 4
       5      23/10/2018      test 5

t2     id      t1_Id        file       category
       1         2          image 1      1
       2         2          image 5      1
       3         4          image 10     1
       4         4          text file    2
       5         4          image 3      1
       6         5          image 2      1
```

result should be

```
      t1_id   date            vac_title     file
       5      23/10/2018      test 5       image 2
       4      22/10/2018      test 4       image 10
       2      20/10/2018      test 2       image 5
```

ordered result by date and get the first row from t2 that matches and category = 1

the second select statement in from clause cant find the related row that matches id

Thanks

Comment: I can't see how you'd return a row for t1_id = 1  as no row in t2 has a t1_id = 1  Is the data correct?

Comment: you are right @PhilS .. edited that . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the solution for my problem ,I wish that it would be useful for somebody .

```
SELECT
t1.title AS title,
t2.int_data_id,
t2.blob_file AS image,
t2.txt_attach_name AS fname,
t2.txt_attach_type AS ftype,
t1.cdate,
t1.id AS aid
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            data_tbl.id AS id,
            data_tbl.int_status AS status,
            data_tbl.int_type AS type,
            data_tbl.txt_title AS title,
            data_tbl.dat_trans_date AS cdate
        FROM
            data_tbl
        ORDER BY
            dat_trans_date DESC
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            int_data_id,
            int_category,
            txt_attach_name,
            blob_file,
            txt_attach_type,
            rownumber
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    int_data_id,
                    int_category,
                    txt_attach_name,
                    txt_attach_type,
                    blob_file,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY int_data_id
                        ORDER BY
                            int_data_id DESC
                    ) AS rownumber
                FROM
                    data_attach_tbl
                WHERE
                    int_category = 1
            ) d
        WHERE
            d.rownumber = 1
        ORDER BY
            int_data_id DESC
    ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.int_data_id
            WHERE t1.type = 11
            AND t1.status >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should get the result:

```
SELECT t1.id as id , t1.title as title ,t2.fId, t2.image as image ,t2.fName as fName, t2.fType as fType
FROM (SELECT i1.id , i1.title, MIN(i2.Id)  as minID -- t2 primary key field
    FROM data_TBL i1
    INNER JOIN data_attach_tbl i2 on i1.id = i2.int_data_id  -- t1 foreign key field in t2
    WHERE i2.int_category = 1
    GROUP BY i1.id ) t1
INNER JOIN data_attach_tbl t2 on t1.minID = t2.Id -- t2 primary key field
ORDER BY t1.date desc;
```

I have ignorred the WHERE clause for t1 for type, status and ROWNUM  as you did not mention them, if you need them should be simple to add them back in to the inner query.

Note I have not tested this in Oracle but it is standard SQL so should hopefully be ok.

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Realised one problem.  I was using the forieign key (the t1 Id) when I should have  using the Id for t2.  I've updated the SQL.  Does that fix it?

Comment: group by blob column .. I just didn't realize that I should mention using blob image column . sorry for that